# Multiple b2ContactListener in same project

Tags: box2d, box2d-iphone

Could someone please advise me if I can add more than one custom b2ContactListener in the same project. I am working on a Brick Breaker game in which I have a custom b2ContactListener for my Ball class that handles collision response when the ball collides with the wall, brick and paddle. I created a 2nd b2ContactListener for my Brick class so it can check if it collided with Ball and perform its own internal stuff e.g.: decrement the number of hits the brick took, play sound, brick destroyed sound, destroy animation, etc.

I am not sure if Box2D allows having multiple b2ContactListeners in the same project, since only one gets fired, whichever one is last set via `world->SetContactListener( contactListener1 );`. I have been googling around for a few hours now but have not been successful in finding an answer.

Please advise.

Comment: One b2World can only have one contact listener. You can have that listener handle all the collisions for various types of objects.

Comment: Thank you iforce2d. I looked into the Box2d library files and the internal variable in the SetContactListener method is called 'something manager'. That threw me off a bit since I assumed that there was some sort of stack keeping track of all the ContactListeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you once again iforce2d for clarifying that there can only be one ContactListener per b2World.